# Eclipse Helios x86 issues on Windows 7 x64, even on clean system

Tags: java, eclipse, 64-bit, windows-7-x64, eclipse-3.6

I have a problem with Eclipse for some time. When I move to Windows 7 x64 on my notebook, Eclipse starts getting "Freeze", for example, when using Content Assist (Code Helper), or using any other option in Eclipse. I am using quite bunch of plugins, so, I tried to delete them all, and check clean IDE. But this didn't help. I downloaded fresh Eclipse Helios for Windows x64, didn't help. I even formated the disk, reinstall Windows, install only JDK and Eclipse but it always occur. What can I do ?

Edit:

Memory: I did not change memory, and IDE freeze, change memory to 512,1024,2048 MB, keeps freezing. (via vm parameters).

Anti-Virus: I am using ESET Smart Security, but with our without it, Eclipse keeps freezing.

Comment: by freeze do you mean pauses for a second or two or that it just starts up and hangs forever. please elaborate

Comment: This might be a hardware issue... my i7 laptop does not have this problem at all. same setup.

Comment: Did you try this `eclipse.ini` file ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659 ) with your Eclipse 3.6.1 installation? It should make Eclipse runs much more smoothly.

Comment: freezeing for about 3-8 seconds, but sometimes longer. VonC, I will try and I will report result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several leads.

1. Check whether this freeze the freeze is linked to a huge consumption of CPU or disk usage.  Unlikely.
2. If not then this is probably a network issue. Then disable the firewall for a while and try again.  Eclipse now reports your plugin usage at the beginning of a session and it might be busy looking for a connection.
3. Close all editors from previous session. In the past, eclipse tried to access xml DTD with from the network instead of the local catalog and that would fail if you were offline of course.

Finally, let me tell you that if this is for running eclipse you've selected the worst OS.  OSX and Linux are much better options.  I used to do so as well.  But for the last two years, I've run Windows only inside VirtualBox when I couldn't avoid it (TOAD, Macromedia Fireworks) and I wished I had migrated before.

Comment: 1. CPU usage - unfortunately yes, something around 70-90%, and memory slightly more (around 350-500 MB on default eclipse.ini). 2. I often work off-line. But disabling firewall didn't work. And I think, I disabled any usage reporting in Preferences. 3. I tried it too. Only one editor, and same effects. And about OSX and Linux: OSX - I don't have a Mac for it, Linux - Recently I don't see any big reasons for changing to it, because I am using some apps that did not have replacements on Linux.

Comment: You can have a look to the log <workspace>/.metadata/.log Or you can monitor the JVM with JMX through a simple -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true (and possibly set a port) in the eclipse.ini and then using the jconsole to monitor CPU usage.

Comment: I tried Linux as you said. Hmm, you are right :) for Java Development it's great :) Ubuntu for Java, Windows 7 for .Net and everyone is happy :)

Answer (score 1):

After much frustration, I disabled AVG and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial point is how much memory you have for Eclipse and if you have any anti-virus software installed that needs to preparse all the class files Eclipse wants to look in.

Does it settle after some usage?

Comment: My answer to your question is above. (This is first time I am using stackoverflow.com)